Reciting “Subhana Rabbial A’la” in sujud?
In naf’l prayer (like Tahajjud), how many times can I recite “Subhana Rabbial A’la” in sujud?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. Please note that this question is very basic, did you do some research effort? Then show it!
